# With Angular update the scope from an event handler

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I am having one issue I was hoping someone would help me on. I am using Angular and the angular google maps directive. I have an event handler registered on idle so that I want to update what markers are shown but when the event is handled it returns the map and I've lost scope so I am unsure how to add new markers onto the map?

I setup a map like so:

```
<google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" events="map.events"> <markers> <marker ng-repeat="marker in map.markers" coords="marker"> </marker> </markers> </google-map>
```

That then uses the following to setup its initial values on events:

```
 $scope.map = {
    center: {
        latitude: 45,
        longitude: -73
    },
    zoom: 8,
    events:{
       idle:getJobs
    },
    markers:[]
};
```

When the event fires the getJobs function I have lost the scope so cannot push new markers onto the map with angular, any ideas??

```
function getJobs($scope) {
    self = this;
    JobService.getJobs(self.map).then(function(jobData){
        for (var i = 0; i < jobData.length; i++) {
            var job = jobData[i];
            if (job.get('location') != null && job.get('location').longitude != null) {
                $scope.map.markers.push(createJobMarker(job.get('role'),job.get('location').longitude,job.get('location').latitude),i);              
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is your event registration?

Comment: the view looks like this:        <google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" events="map.events">
            <markers>
                <marker ng-repeat="marker in map.markers" coords="marker">
                </marker>
            </markers>
        </google-map>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function getJobs($scope) {
    self = this;
    JobService.getJobs(self.map).then(function(jobData){
        $scope.apply(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < jobData.length; i++) {
                var job = jobData[i];
                if (job.get('location') != null && job.get('location').longitude != null) {
                    $scope.map.markers.push(createJobMarker(job.get('role'),job.get('location').longitude,job.get('location').latitude),i);              
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Update:

I see, you are just losing reference to the scope variable. Try setting up your event like this:

```
$scope.map = {
    center: {
        latitude: 45,
        longitude: -73
    },
    zoom: 8,
    events:{
       idle: function () {
           getJobs($scope);
       }
    },
    markers:[]
};
```

Comment: Hi it still fails at the same place $scope is null when you call apply :(

Comment: Well that's the best I could offer since you're not showing us where you call `getJobs` or where you register your event handler.

Comment: Ok I have included the map markup in the main question. Its using the events variable I have defined in the map model. It fires ok but then it passes in the map but I have no access to the scope

Comment: It does not seem very elegant but I got it working with this:   var scope = angular.element($('#MapPage')).scope() then used the scope instead of $scope

Comment: You're getting reference to the scope via the lower-level scope function provided by angular. Check out my update to my answer if you want to avoid doing that.

Comment: I didn't want to cause confusion in my answer, but you could also do `idle: getJobs.bind(this, $scope)` to make it more succinct :)